# FFMPEG how to select only one file and compress it in another format

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, command-line, ffmpeg

In ruby I can now compress all the .mp4 of the folder into .webm.

```
    Dir.glob("*.mp4") do |my_text_file|
        puts ' --> converting: ' + my_text_file
        puts "ffmpeg -i #{my_text_file.gsub(/ /, '\ ')} -b:v 640k  #{my_text_file.gsub(/.mp4/, '')}.webm"
        `ffmpeg -i #{my_text_file.gsub(/ /, '\ ')} -b:v 640k  #{my_text_file.gsub(/.mp4/, '')}.webm`
    end
```

And now how could I select a specific file? I tried this:

```
    aa = params[:file].to_s
    Dir.glob("#{aa}") do |my_text_file|
        puts ' --> converting: ' + my_text_file
        puts "ffmpeg -i #{my_text_file.gsub(/ /, '\ ')} -b:v 640k  #{my_text_file.gsub(/.mp4/, '')}.webm"
    `ffmpeg -i #{my_text_file.gsub(/ /, '\ ')} -b:v 640k  #{my_text_file.gsub(/.mp4/, '')}.webm`
    end
```

Comment: The result of the second script is null, ffmpeg doesn't find the file I'd like to compress. I had to change directory before executing the ffmpeg script like this: Dir.chdir "/var/rails_app/xxx/public/uploads/#{current_user.email}/"

Comment: if I rename manually a mp4 with a filename like current_user.email.mp4 and I write 
Dir.glob("#{current_user.email}") instead of the var aa, ffmpeg find the file and compress it like a charm. It means it is possible ton insert a variable right here. But what kind of variable should I use?
I tried session and @myfile and params[:file] that is in the url.

Comment: You could assign "my_text_file" to your specific filename...and remove the `Dir..do` and `end` lines...

Answer (score 0):

I'm so sorry, I was working with the original filename instead of the physical name on disk as the file is renamed by program. So you just have to put

```
    `Dir.glob("#{params[:file]}")`
```